# How do I combine activities from multiple rows into one list/cell in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, csv

I need your help!

Now I have **two data frames/.csvs for each of our two customers** (please refer to the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ4Rg.png)) with each action flow. However, since we have many customers to analyze I would like to **transform it into a single one with rows each presenting one customer and his or her action flow in a list** (please refer now to the third df in the picture  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ4Rg.png)).

Thank you in advance,
Marius

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can see where the error is when you run the data. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
library(dplyr)

p <- 1;
new_col <- c();
for (i in unique(df$Customer_ID)){
  a <- subset(df,df$Customer_ID==i)
  s <- paste(a$action,sep="",collapse = ",") %>% paste("c(",.,")",sep="")
  new_col[p] <- s
  p <- p+1
}


new_df <- cbind(unique(df$Customer_ID),s) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(new_df) <- c("Customer ID","Actions")

head(new_df)
```

So suppose our df is called " df ", which contains " Customer_ID " and " Actions ". Subset df in unique of Customer_ID values, and then paste all actions of that ID.

**NOTE** that the desired output class would be a "list", but instead this is a `paste` function, so a character string may appear instead of a list.

If this is a problem, consider subtracting each element in this " character " collapsed with `,` and assign that element to any component of the desired list.

Save that " character " into a variable, lets say `s`, and that variable to a vector called `new_column`. Finally just add the unique of `customers ID` with each value `s` and change its column names.